# Conjugacy class of Alternating group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Any advice on the determination of all the conjugacy classes of subgroups of $A_{4}$

For eg, $H_{1} = \left\{(1), (1,2)(3,4)\right\}, H_{2}= \left\{(1), (1,4)(2,3)\right\} $ are subgroups of $A_{4}$ and how do I find $g\in A_{4}$ such that $H_{1} = gH_{2}g^{-1}$

Comment: These are not subgroups. $(1,2)$ is not in $A_4$. Perhaps you mean $(12)(34)$?

Comment: Look at the [ConjugacyClass](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GroupTheory/ConjugacyClass) command of Maple to this end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : For any transposition $\sigma = (ij)$, and any $\tau \in A_4$
$$
\tau\sigma \tau^{-1} = (\tau(i) \tau(j))
$$

Edit : To complete the answer, you are looking for a $g\in A_4$ such that
$$
g(12)(34)g^{-1} = (14)(23)
$$
So take
$$
g = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 4 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(ie. $(12)(34) \mapsto (14)(23)$ "term-wise")

Comment: Yes, but the same argument applies to $(12)(34)$ since they are disjoint cycles.

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks. Just corrected it.

Comment: Conjugate in $A_4$ or in $S_4$?

Comment: @TedShifrin : I don't understand your question. Could you explain? The OP asked how to find a $g$ as above, and the hint helps you find such a $g$.

Comment: Are you sure? I just plugged it in, and it gives me $g = (243)$, which is in $A_4$

Comment: Yeah, I found an obvious one in $S_4$. You're right, of course. For me, it's easier to think of $A_4$ as the symmetry group of a regular tetrahedron. :)

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Could you advise on how you find $g=(243)$ ?